# Site Page looks different in Safari as opposed to Chrome

Tags: html, css, safari

I am currently almost done constructing a site. When I go to preview in my browser, there is one page that, when opened in Chrome, the Nav Bar and text gets smaller. This is the only page that does this, and again, it only happens in Safari. When I open in Safari and Firefox, it works like it should. All the pages link to the same stylesheet and style reference. Any ideas?

```css
#header {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #000066, blue);
  background-position: left;
  min-width: 1070px;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <a href="index.html">
    <img src="Images/Eagle.png" alt="EJP Electric" id="homepage">
  </a>
  <div id="contact">Office: (231)-775-3799
    <br>Cell: (231)-920-3067

  </div>
  <nav id="main_nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="services.html">Pricing</li>
     <li><a href="WhyEJP.html">Why EJP</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact EJP</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Could you share the code that creates the Nav Bar?

Comment: Let me edit my question for you though, I got Safari and Chrome backwards.  It displays properly in Safari and not in Chrome.

Comment: If my answer did not solve your problem, it may come down to browser dependency.  Chrome uses a different font rendering engine so it may be something there.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like you are missing a closing tag after pricing:

```
<li><a href="services.html">Pricing   </a>  </li>
```

Comment: I did fix that, thanks for catching that.  I don't know how I missed something so small.  But that didn't fix the problem.  It is just one of those weird things where I keep going over the code and can't find a difference.  My header text and everything is the same throughout all the pages, and I don't know why it does something so silly like that.  Thanks again though.